# How to make constructor prototype enumerable?

Tags: javascript

How can I make prototype getTaggedTweet enumerable so no can access this prototype from outside? Can I do it by using the defineProperty method of an object?

```js
function Tweet_api(tweetID){}
Tweet_api.prototype.getTweetByHandler = async function(){
    const data = await this.getTaggedTweet.call(null, 'handler');
    return data;
};
Tweet_api.prototype.getTweetByHashtag = async function(){
    const data = await this.getTaggedTweet.call(null, 'hashtag');
    return data;
};
Tweet_api.prototype.getTaggedTweet = function(method){
    return method === 'handler' ? '@' : '#';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a property enumerable or non-enumerable will not affect whether it's accessible from the outside or not. If it's a property, it *will* be accessible regardless, with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, which iterates over non-enumerable properties as well.

```js
const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'amIPrivate', {
  value: 'no',
  enumerable: false
});

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((prop) => {
  console.log(obj[prop]);
});
```

Rather, you can make sure the outside cannot access your method using a *closure* - make an IIFE which defines the class and the (private, standalone) function inside it, then return the class:

```
const Tweet_api = (() => {
  function Tweet_api(tweetID) {}
  Tweet_api.prototype.getTweetByHandler = async function() {
    const data = await getTaggedTweet.call(null, 'handler');
    return data;
  };
  Tweet_api.prototype.getTweetByHashtag = async function() {
    const data = await getTaggedTweet.call(null, 'hashtag');
    return data;
  };
  const getTaggedTweet = method => method === 'handler' ? '@' : '#';
  return Tweet_api;
})();
```

Also note that there's no need to `await` things that aren't Promises.